# Frequency pairs of more than one tokens

Tags: r

Having a dataframe like this one:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4), stocks = c("google stock, yahoo product stock", "google stock, yahoo product stock","yahoo product stock", "google stock"))
```

How is it possible to take a pair frequency table like this:

```
google stock - yahoo product stock 2
google stock                       1
yahoo product stock                1
```

Comment: Isn't this similar to the earlier question

Comment: @akrun it has more than one tokens

Comment: @akrun I tried com but the separator is not working

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this :

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4), stocks = c("google stock, yahoo product stock",
                                             "google stock, yahoo product stock",
                                             "yahoo product stock",
                                             "google stock"))

table(df$stocks)
```